# Name server propagation for sub sub domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

I face a problem for adding a DNS record to a sub sub domain ("*x.y.example.com*").

> To explain the architecture further :
>
> - "*example.com*" is my commercial website. NS records are set from my provider
> - "*y.example.com*" is used by a thrid party emailing to manage my email campaigns. it have a A record to thier server and use custom NS records to thier name server.
> - "*x.y.example.com*" is used to track link on emails. it have a A record to the same server as "*y.example.com"*.

I have to add a CNAME record to "*x.y.example.com*" to validate a ssl certificate creation.

My first thought was to add the CNAME record on my DNS records from my "*example.com*" provider. So, i add the CNAME record to "*x.y.example.com*" (strangly, it was not created on my sub-domains, I recreated it and added the DNS records).
After waiting few days, It doesn't work.

After searching a bit about this issue, i found that the DNS are read starts by "*.com*" then "*example.com*" then "*y.example.com*" and finally "*x.y.example.com*".
So if my DNS records are stored on the name server from my emailing thrid party for the sub domain "*y.example.com*", then all sub domain of "*y.example.com*" use the same name servers. Right ?

I think the A record from "*x.y.example.com*" has been added to name servers of the third party and this is why i hadn't this sub sub domain registred on my own DNS (name server).

May I have to ask the guys from the third party emailing provider to add the CNAME record on thier name servers ?

Thanks

EDIT: Serverfault first consider my question as spam. So i decided to rewrite all domains. My first attempt was "track(dot)mail(dot)mydomain.com". Sorry for the unreadable "x.y.example.com".

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! In many cases mentioning the actual domain name is essential for the community to be able to help diagnose DNS issues. This may be one too. Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions. Use `code markup` around  your domain / hostnames to prevent automated hyperlink expansions and spam triggers.

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn. I will be careful and read the Q&A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you've delegated the subdomain for `y.example.com` to another provider then any records in that subdomain, including anything below it like `x.y.example.com` will be controlled by that provider.

If you had another subdomain, for instance `z.example.com` that wasn't delegated elsewhere, then only then would it be controlled by the same servers as the main `example.com` domain.

So unless they have some kind of control panel to let you make changes to it, you'd need to get the third party marketing company to add that record to your subdomain that they control/manage for you.